# Nvidia Server Settings does not see all GPUs

Tags: nvidia, gpu-driver

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
4 x GTX 1060 graphics cards connected.

```
lspci | grep 'VGA' says:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5902 (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c03 (rev a1)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c03 (rev a1)
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c03 (rev a1)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c03 (rev a1)
```

but the Nvidia X Server Settings only shows GPU0, GPU1 and GPU2. Any idea why they are not all appearing and working?